# 3'rd party cookie - advertisers - implementation clarification?

Tags: javascript, cookies, cross-domain, same-origin-policy, ads

*As I'm reading a lot about third party javascript/cookies - I have an implementation question.*

I've seen [***this slide show (#45)***](http://www.slideshare.net/SlexAxton/breaking-the-cross-domain-barrier) *(the context of the slide is about cross domain but it is used also for advertisers)*

[image]

AFAIK it goes like this :

- First enterence to Site #1  : the site has  a page .that page also holds an advertiser  `iframe` from `TotalNotTrackingYou.com`.
  The `SRC` of the iframe has  general info for that *particular* page content ( *if any* ).
  So `TotalNotTrackingYou.com` sends a `cookie` with identification token when the page #1 loads .
  This way - when you browse to *other* pages besides site #1 ( **notice** ! the user **didn't** click on any add yet !) - `TotalNotTrackingYou.com` knows what intereting topics you are interested .
- Now the user has left site #1 and went to site #2 which also holds an iframe from `TotalNotTrackingYou.com`. Same goes here.  the cookie which was generated by site #1 request (*which in turn loads an iframe*) - is sent back to `TotalNotTrackingYou.com` which again - reads the referrer and the relevant querystring (at SRC) for that iframe .
- `TotalNotTrackingYou.com` (sends you cookies when their iframe loads at sites #1..#5) and learning only your navigation habbit (using referrer - which site you were on).**But** when you click on the advertising add - `TotalNotTrackingYou.com` now knows for sure what you are intereted in , and they add it to their db.
  from now on - all sites (which holds `TotalNotTrackingYou.com` iframe) will send relevant adds according to  the user interests list..

  **Question**

  A script reference `<script src='www.TotalNotTrackingYou.com/cookiecreator.ashx' />` can also send / recieve cookies. So why advertisers don't  use `scripts` but `iframes` ?

*Additional info.*
I know that 3rd party cookies are disabled by default in Safari. but there is a hack to create an iframe and a form and to post that form to that iframe - which will write cookie.

Comment: +1 for the safari hack mentioned

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This hack in safari to allow 3rd party cookies by posting was fixed. (Btw, Google also received a hefty fine from the FCC for exploiting this "hack": http://www.theverge.com/2012/7/31/3207388/fcc-approval-google-fine-safari-cookies )

In any case, the reason that they use iframes is because the preferred method for storing data associated with the 3rd-party domain is no longer a 3rd party cookie, but instead localStorage. To access the localStorage of the 3rd-party domain, the javascript code has to be running under a document from that domain, hence why the iframe works, and not a script loaded on the 1st party domain.

The benefits of localStorage vs the cookie is that it's not blocked even when the user requests blocking of 3rd-party cookies. See for example this thread from Firefox development:
https://bugzilla.mozilla.org/show_bug.cgi?id=536509 or this article running through the code itself http://log.scalemotion.com/2012/10/how-to-trick-safari-and-set-3rd-party.html

Comment: But every site that uses iframe for advertising - when i look at chrome -  i see many third domain cookies ( persistent).  - not localstorage. Also how does `TotalNotTrackingYou.com` know which product ive clicked on ? are you telling me that there is a SRC change url foreach click on a product ?

Comment: 3rd-party cookies do still have benefits:
- IE6 & IE7 do not support localStorage
- They can be shared across protocols (http/https) which might be an issue since the iframe would likely use the protocol of the page

Every page you visit typically sends its entire URL to the 3rd-party tracker. (Even if it did not do so explicitly in the querystring, it would normally do so in the referrer anyway)

Comment: Here's another good resource on the technical aspects of using frames for cross-domain information passing:
http://softwareas.com/cross-domain-communication-with-iframes

Comment: How does `TotalNotTrackingYou.com` knows which product ive clicked on ?  ( im not talking about clicking the Ad  - but other links on the page) --are you telling me that there is a `Iframe SRC` change url foreach click on a link ?

Comment: Well typically when you click on a product, you open a new page. This new page also sends tracking to the third party server. Some solutions   also use a redirect through their server to track clicks (such as, I believe, Rich Relevance)

Comment: If you mean clicking on an ad from this ad network, then almost always you will see a redirect through one of their URLs.

Comment: Fabio - But when I'm on page A and I click on glasses ( not an Ad) - I go to another page B. now how does the third party site knows ive clicked on Glasses ? (the third side published knows nothing about the query string nor id).

Comment: 1) If the target of the link is on the original site, the new page will be tracked like to the first page.
2) If the target of the link is on another site, which also participates in the ad network, the new page will be tracked like to the first page.
3) If the target of the link is on another site, which does NOT participate in the ad network, the new page will not be tracked. In theory, a JS file like you mentioned on the 1st party domain would allow link-onclick/page-onunload tracking, but I don't think any ad networks do this, nor do I think it would go over well with site owners or users

Comment: _"the new page will be tracked like to the first page"_ --sorry but I don't understand. how does `TotalNotTrackingYou.com` know (page A or B) that i **clicked on glasses** ?  is it related to meta tags / title ?

Comment: They know the URL of the target page because they also have their tracking on it. As far as knowing that this page relates to glasses, I'm sure it's different for each ad network. Some of them just track demographics and domain-level subjects, some of them are more deeply integrated in the 1st-party sites (e.g. sitemaps and datafeeds), some may simply crawl the tracked URLs and do content analysis, but all that is beyond the scope of user tracking I think...